# Unable to store the file in App_data folder in ASP.NET folder using HttpPostedFileBase Save method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to resolve this issue

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["vendorsEditUploadCertBlockName" + cr];
if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs("~/App_Data/uploads/certifications/" + insertCert.CERTIFICATION_ID + "/" + fileName);
}
```

The code throws the following exception

> The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/App_Data/uploads/certifications/12/us.png' is not rooted
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/App_Data/uploads/certifications/12/us.png' is not rooted

Comment: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/App_Data/uploads/certifications/12/us.png' is not rooted.

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/App_Data/uploads/certifications/12/us.png' is not rooted.

Comment: Use [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx). Refer also [Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/)

Comment: And please delete your comments (add additional information to you question, not comments)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `HttpContext.Server.MapPath` to map desired path for file saving:

```
string yourPath="~/App_Data/uploads/certifications/" + insertCert.CERTIFICATION_ID + "/" + fileName;
file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath(yourPath));
```